# Angular 1 directive component has different behavior in modal and out of the modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, treeview

I am really struggling with the issue with custom directive component. I have created TreeView dropdown component based on Angular ivh-treeview [angular-ivh-treeview](https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview). Becasue ivh-treeview by default does not have recommended functionality and stylig I have extend it. But now I am facing an issue I haven't seen before and I would be really thankful for your help. The component works absolutelly OK in the modal. When you click on the checkboxes it reacts pretty fast and everything looks great. But when I use the same component on any other  page (not in the modal) it has really strange behavior. When you select any checkbox, it does not update immediatelly, you have to click somewhere else on the page, or close and open dropdown to see changes. I have no clue what is going on there and why the same component works in the modal. Maybe it's because modalInstance has different scope but I am done.

Here you can see and play with an example (Page 1 - modal, Page 2 - no modal): [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ugv90PPkGiVdrT1DEKki?p=preview)

This is just a fragment of the code I had to include to be able to link here DEMO on Plunkr

```
<ivh-dropdown ivh-model="treeStructureFinal" selected-array="formData.casinos" is-disabled="inReadMode" placeholder="Select casinos"></ivh-dropdown>
```

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this kind of thing happens I always think about `$scope.$apply()`.

So I did a minor modification and now the directive works fine, just by adding a `scope.$apply` at the end of the click handler:

```
        $document.bind('click', function (event) {
            var isClickedElementChildOfPopup = element.find(
                    event.target).length > 0;
            if (!isClickedElementChildOfPopup
                && element[0].children[1].classList.contains("show")) {
                element[0].children[1].classList.toggle("show");
            }
            scope.$apply();
        });
```

Take a look at it working:
https://plnkr.co/edit/s1UNCXNCZ46zXjte9lpZ?p=preview

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you a lot Fedaykin. You really helped me. What a magical line of code. I am going to read about it more. Thank you.